# Can't Figure Out how to make my minimap work

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I cant seem to find a way to make the turtle goto specific areas on the map when people type in the desire location like south i know that when using the setx and sety lines that it will send it to the coords i mapped out the cords 
x starting area 175 each sqaure is 50 apart | Y starting area 380 each sqaure is 50 apart. I Am Not Using Pygame since i want to Present it at school

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
####################LOUIS'S STORY###################
class Theif_Story():

def Map_Starting_Area():
    import turtle
    # X axis = 1 -> 5
    # Y axis = A -> E
    ########Compass#######
    turtle.speed(99)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.fd(150)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.fd(75)
    turtle.backward(150)
    turtle.fd(75)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(75)
    turtle.backward(150)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(10)
    turtle.write('W')
    turtle.fd(10)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.fd(150)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.fd(10)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.write('E')
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(10)
    turtle.backward(75)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.fd(75)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.fd(20)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.write('S')
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(10)
    turtle.backward(170)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.write('N')
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.backward(225)
    turtle.pd()
    ####################
    #######Grid###########
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.ht()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)

    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(250)

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(250)

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(250)

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)

    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(250)
    turtle.left(90)

    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(250)
    turtle.left(90)

    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(250)
    turtle.left(90)

    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.backward(250)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.st()
    ############
    # Square = Town
    # Circle = Fight
    # Arrow = Quest Marker
    # Turtle = Weapon Shops
    # Triangle = Potion Shop
    # hollow circle = chest
    turtle.backward(175)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.forward(75)
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.shape("classic")
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(150)
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.shape("arrow")
    turtle.color("blue")
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.color("black")
    turtle.shape("classic")
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.fd(100)
    turtle.shape("circle")
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.shape("classic")
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.shape("circle")
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.shape("classic")
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.fd(100)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.fd(50)
    turtle.shape("circle")
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.shape("classic")
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.fd(200)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.fd(100)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.fd(10)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.circle(10)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.fd(140)
    turtle.color('blue')
    turtle.rt(90)

import random
import time
import turtle

Wooden_Chest_Item_List = 'Wooden Short Blade', 'Wooden Axe', 'Wooden Stick', 'Wooden Long Blade', 'Stone Short Blade', 'Stone Axe', 'Stone Wand', 'Stone Long Blade', 'Iron Short Blade', 'Iron Axe', 'Iron Wand', 'Iron Long Blade', 'Diamond Short Blade', 'Diamond Axe', 'Diamond Wand', 'Diamond Long Blade'
Weapon_Chest = random.choice(Wooden_Chest_Item_List)

Potion_Use_Per_Battle = 3
Life = 100
Foe = random.randint(25, 150)
Player_Dmg = 25
Magic_Dmg = 10
Foe_Dmg = 15
Fists = Player_Dmg
Weapon = Fists

Wooden_Short_Blade = Player_Dmg + 3
Wooden_Stick = Magic_Dmg + 5
Wooden_Axe = Player_Dmg + 4
Wooden_Long_Blade = Player_Dmg + 5

Stone_Short_Blade = Player_Dmg + 5
Stone_Axe = Player_Dmg + 6
Stone_Wand = Magic_Dmg + 7
Stone_Long_Blade = Player_Dmg + 7

Iron_Short_Blade = Player_Dmg + 7
Iron_Axe = Player_Dmg + 8
Iron_Wand = Magic_Dmg + 9
Iron_Long_Blade = Player_Dmg + 9

Diamond_Short_Blade = Player_Dmg + 9
Diamond_Axe = Player_Dmg + 10
Diamond_Wand = Magic_Dmg + 11
Diamond_Long_Blade = Player_Dmg + 11
Bupe_Doop = Player_Dmg + Magic_Dmg + 5 ##Louis's Custom Weopon

Small_Health_Potion_Amount = random.randint(0,3)
Medium_Health_Potion_Amount = random.randint(0,3)
Large_Health_Potion_Amount = random.randint(0,3)


print('You Continue with your Journey')
print('You leave the protection of your farm and head into the open land')
print(Map_Starting_Area())
print('You Come to a cross road')
print('Would you like to go South, West or East ')
Direction = str(input())
if Direction == 'South':
    turtle.sety(330)
    turtle.update()
elif Direction == 'East':
    turtle.setx(225)
    turtle.update()
elif Direction == 'West':
    turtle.setx(125)
    turtle.update()
print('Which way do you go')
Direction2 = str(input())
if Direction2 == 'South':
    turtle.sety(330) #Stuck on this part since theirs 3 diffrent solution
    turtle.update()
elif Direction2 == 'East':
    turtle.setx(225)
    turtle.update
elif Direction2 == 'West':
    turtle.setx(125)
    turtle.update()
    print('You encounter a raverous Spider! do you wish to fight it?')
    Fight = str(input())
    if Fight == 'Yes':
        #########Battle Code Warrior############
        import random
        import time


        While_Loop = 1
        ###########Battle 1############
        print("""Spider Appers, You Need to do 10 dmg to kill this enemy!!!""")
        print('============================================')
        while While_Loop == 1:
                if Foe >= 0:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print('You did', Player_Dmg,'Dmg')
                    Foe = Foe - Player_Dmg
                    print('Your Foe has ',Foe,'Hp left')
                    print('=============================')
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    Player_Dmg = random.randrange(0,10)
                    if Foe <= 0:
                        print('You killed it')
                        break

                    else:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        if life >= 0:
                            life = life - Foe_Dmg
                            print('You took ', Foe_Dmg,'Dmg')
                            print('You Have', life, 'Hp left')
                            print('=============================')
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            Foe_Dmg = random.randrange(0, 10)
                            if life <= 0:
                                print('You are dead')

                else:
                    print('You die')
                    life = 0
                    break

    elif Fight == 'No':
        print('You Sprint Frantically away from the spider while it chases you down!')
        turtle.backward(100)
elif Direction2 == 'South':
    turtle.fd(50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've extracted just enough of your code below to create an example that lets you move the turtle (blue circle) around a 5 x 5 grid using the commands North, South, East & West at the console:

```
import turtle

GRID_UNIT = 50
GRID_SIZE = 5  # code below assumes this is an odd number

def Map_Starting_Area():

    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(-GRID_SIZE/2 * GRID_UNIT, -GRID_SIZE/2 * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.ht()
    turtle.pd()

    ####### Grid ###########

    for _ in range(GRID_SIZE // 2):
        turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)

    for _ in range(GRID_SIZE // 2):
        turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(GRID_SIZE * GRID_UNIT)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.home()

    turtle.st()

turtle.speed('fastest')

Map_Starting_Area()

turtle.color('blue')
turtle.shape('circle')

print('You Continue with your Journey')
print('You leave the protection of your farm and head into the open land')
print('You Come to a cross road')

while True:
    direction = input('Would you like to go North, South, East or West: ').lower()

    if direction == 'north' and turtle.ycor() < GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
        turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + GRID_UNIT)
    elif direction == 'south' and turtle.ycor() > -GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
        turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - GRID_UNIT)
    elif direction == 'east' and turtle.xcor() < GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
        turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + GRID_UNIT)
    elif direction == 'west' and turtle.xcor() > -GRID_UNIT * (GRID_SIZE//2 - 0.5):
        turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() - GRID_UNIT)

    elif direction == 'quit':
        break
```

The code prevents your turtle from leaving the grid.  I've centered the grid at (0, 0) to simplify the logic.  Hopefully you can incorporate this into your program to control the turtle's motion.

Normally, I'd avoid a `while True:` in a turtle program, which really should be event-based, but for now it seems the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks! This should help